# Max value at specific year with a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. `Key` is `SID` in both - the `join` is on this `key`
First table has education data. eg `SID`, Year qualification obtained (`YearQual`) and  `QualLevel`. There may be several `rows` for each `SID`

The second table has `event data` incl. year of the event (`EventYear`), and `SID`

What I need to find is the `MAX` `QualLevel` for the EventYear.

I am using SQL Server.

I have written `query` after `query` and I can get the `MAX`  `QualLevel` ever (unrelated to `event year`) or multiple rows showing all the `qualification levels` >= `event year` when I just want the `MAX` at that year.

```
SELECT eventdata.S_ID, eventdata.eventyear,
     max (education.qual_Level) as highqual
FROM education
  left join eventdata
  ON education.S_ID = eventdata.S_ID
  WHERE  education.YearQual<= eventyear 
  GROUP BY eventyear, qual_level, eventdata.S_ID
```

The above code gives multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to use `apply`:

```
SELECT ed.*, e.qual_Level as highqual
FROM eventdata ed OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) ed.*
      FROM education e
      WHERE e.S_ID = ed.S_ID AND
            e.YearQual <= ed.eventyear 
      ORDER BY e.YearQual DESC
     ) ed;
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to find is the MAX QualLevel for the EventYear.

If you want `MAX` `QualLevel` and the `EventYear`, don't include `eventdata.S_ID` in your `select` and `group by` statement.

As you have multiple `S_ID` for the same `eventyear`, so you will get duplicate records.

Change your query like following.

```
SELECT  eventdata.eventyear,
        max (education.qual_Level) as highqual
FROM education
  left join eventdata
  ON education.S_ID = eventdata.S_ID
  WHERE  education.YearQual<= eventdata.eventyear 
  GROUP BY eventdata.eventyear
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()`

```
 select S_ID,eventyear,highqual from
(SELECT eventdata.S_ID, eventdata.eventyear,
     education.qual_Level as highqual,
  row_number()over(partition by eventyear order by education.qual_Level desc) rn
FROM education
  left join eventdata
  ON education.S_ID = eventdata.S_ID
  WHERE  education.YearQual<= eventyear 
) t where t.rn=1
```